# Zend Framework - Doctrine2 - Change Repository Autoload Location?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I've got a Zend Framework project with Doctrine 2 integrated. The project structure looks like the below:

```
|Project
    |-Application
        |-api
        |-configs
        |-controllers
        |-models
            |-Entities
                |-UserManagement
                    |-Users.php
                    |-Passwords.php
            |-Proxies
            |-Repositories
                |-UserManagement
                    |-UsersRepository.php
                    |-PasswordsRepository.php
        |-modules
        |-views
        |-Bootstrap.php
    |-Docs
    |-Library
    |-Public
    |-.zfproject.xml
```

And whenever I try and use a Repository, for some reason it tried to load it from the entities folder structure and I get this error message:

```
Warning: require(M:\mysite\application/models/entities\UserManagement\UsersRepository.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in M:\mysite\library\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php on line 163
```

What I need to do is change the pathway Doctrine 2 is looking at for the Repositories, but everthing I try doesn't seem to work.

How do I set the repository pathway?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got some disagreement somewhere (include path? autoloader?) about which `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to use. You're on windowz, so it should be backslash (), but i see some forward slashes in there (/).